# Change button text while disabled

Tags: vb.net, button, text

I'm trying to change the text of a button while it is disabled. I have a background worker that is called when the button is pressed, and I'm trying to get the button to be disabled for 5 seconds, with the text on the button indicating the time remaining before the button is enabled again.

The following is my code, with irrelevant bits removed:

```
    Private Sub btnDispense_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDispense.Click
        btnDispense.Enabled = False
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

' Lots of my irrelevant code in here.

    Private Sub bgwWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        ' Changes button text from 5 to 1, with threading to keep time.
        btnDispense.Text = "Dispense (-1) [5]"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        btnDispense.Text = "Dispense (-1) [4]"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        btnDispense.Text = "Dispense (-1) [3]"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        btnDispense.Text = "Dispense (-1) [2]"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        btnDispense.Text = "Dispense (-1) [1]"
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        ' Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.
        btnDispense.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

When I try and run this, there are no errors, so my syntax is okay. The only problem I have is that the text on the button does not change; is this because the button is disabled? I don't know how I'd go about making this work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A button's text can be changed regardless of whether it's enabled or disabled. Your problem is that you can't directly update a UI control from the background worker, either use a delegate or the worker's progress update event.

Comment: How would I use the worker progress update event? I'm looking at the MSDN page for it, but the information isn't that clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your example:

```
Private Sub btnDispense_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDispense.Click
    bgwWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    btnDispense.Enabled = False
    bgwWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgwWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwWorker.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Dispense (-1) [5]")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Dispense (-1) [4]")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Dispense (-1) [3]")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Dispense (-1) [2]")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, "Dispense (-1) [1]")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub

Private Sub bgwWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwWorker.ProgressChanged
    btnDispense.Text = e.UserState.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub bgwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    btnDispense.Enabled = True
End Sub
```